# Install kubernetes dashboard for Raspberry Pi ARM cluster error

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi

I am following the instructions from this link:
https://kubecloud.io/kubernetes-dashboard-on-arm-with-rbac-61309310a640

and I run this command:

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/72832429656c74c4c568ad5b7163fa9716c3e0ec/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard-arm.yaml
```

But I'm getting this output/error:

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/72832429656c74c4c568ad5b7163fa9716c3e0ec/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard-arm.yaml
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-certs created
serviceaccount/kubernetes-dashboard created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
service/kubernetes-dashboard created
error: unable to recognize "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/72832429656c74c4c568ad5b7163fa9716c3e0ec/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard-arm.yaml": no match
es for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1beta2"
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here?
I'm trying to install the Kubernetes Dashboard for a Raspberry PI cluster.

Here is  my setup:

```
pi@k8s-master:/etc/kubernetes$ kubectl get nodes
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
k8s-master   Ready    master   2d11h   v1.16.2
k8s-node1    Ready    worker   2d3h    v1.16.2
k8s-node2    Ready    worker   2d2h    v1.15.2
k8s-node3    Ready    worker   2d2h    v1.16.2
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind your error is that after 1.16.0 kubernetes stopped using `apps/v1beta2`for deployments. You should use `apps/v1` instead.

Please donwnload the file:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/72832429656c74c4c568ad5b7163fa9716c3e0ec/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard-arm.yaml
```

Edit the file using `nano` or `vi` and change the deployment api version to `apps/v1`.

Don`t forget to save the file when exiting.

Then:

```
kubectl apply -f [file_name]
```

You may find more about there release changes [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16).